# Add library path after system path

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm looking for something like `-idirafter`, but for libraries rather than includes.

I'm building GCC for macOS, with the intention that my users can run it on any OS release from El Capitan up. Until Big Sur there wasn't a problem with libraries; I could build on my old laptop running El Capitan and sort out the include paths so as to look in the Xcode SDK if there was no `/usr/include` (this happened at Mojave).

With Big Sur, Apple have decided to treat `/usr/lib` similarly, so I've added this in the `specs` file:

```
*lib:
%{!static:
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib -lSystem}
```

but the result of this is that a link uses

```
Library search paths:
    /opt/gcc-11.0.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15/11.0.0
    /opt/gcc-11.0.0/lib/gcc
    /opt/gcc-11.0.0/lib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
```

i.e. the SDK paths come before `/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`, which works fine on Catalina but fails on El Capitan with

```
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib for architecture x86_64
```

(I think what's happening here is that there's an inconsistency between the SDK and the actual libraries)